# Apache Spark TFIDF using Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

The Spark documentation states to use `HashingTF` feature, but I'm unsure what the transform function expects as input. 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#tf-idf

I tried running the tutorial code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.feature import HashingTF

sc = SparkContext()

# Load documents (one per line).
documents = sc.textFile("...").map(lambda line: line.split(" "))

hashingTF = HashingTF()
tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/salloumm/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 114, in transform
    return self._transform(dataset)
  File "/Users/salloumm/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 148, in _transform
    return DataFrame(self._java_obj.transform(dataset._jdf), dataset.sql_ctx)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

Comment: Could you show us exactly the code you tried?

Comment: I tried the first example shown in this link  (The example in Python) http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#tf-idf                   Used a simple text file as input.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error you've shown it is clear you don't follow the tutorial or use code included in the question.

This error is a result of using `from pyspark.ml.feature.HashingTF` instead of `pyspark.mllib.feature.HashingTF`. Just clean your environment and make sure you use correct imports.